# TRACE32 breakpoint issue

Tags: breakpoints, trace32, lauterbach

I have a development board which runs with Linux and other stuff. I boot the board and load the Linux symbols and i put the break point at known place. Though breakpoint gets hit, within 2 sec the state of the board changes from "Stopped by breakpoint" to "Runnning". It is really giving me a problem because i'm not able properly debug.

Any TRACE32 breakpoint setting i missed or it is board specific?

Comment: This really sounds like a watchdog issue... If you have a watchdog timer, try to disable it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes! you are right. It is watchdog timer issue.